# Google Polymer - Pass data from iron-list to custom element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to pass data fetched from JSON via an `iron-list` element, but I can't get this to work.

I've set the default value in my custom `<user-status>` element to the `status` object which is showing up correctly, it's just the JSON that doesn't seem to get passed along within the `<iron-list>`.

**What do I need to change in order for the `status` object from the `<iron-list>`, to be passed to my `<user-status>` element?**

I am using Polymer 1.0

This is the JSON that's beeing fetched:

```
[
    {
        "message":              "diam imperdiet mattis sit amet mattis erat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur dolor neque, lacinia eu fringilla id, pharetra id libero. Fusce sed vestibulum augue."
    },
    {
        "message":              "diam imperdiet mattis sit amet mattis erat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur dolor neque, lacinia eu fringilla id, pharetra id libero. Fusce sed vestibulum augue."
    }
]
```

This is the relevant HTML in the `index.html`:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <iron-ajax url="/statuses.json" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax>
  <iron-list items="[[data]]" as "status">
    <template>
      <user-status status="[[status]]"></user-status>
    </template>
  </iron-list>
</template>
```

And this is my `user-status.html` element:

```
<dom-module id="user-status">
  <template>
    <paper-material user-status-container elevation="1">
      <div user-status-message-content><span>{{status.message}}</span></div>
    </paper-material>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({

    is: 'user-status',

    properties: {
      status: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
          return {
            message: 'This content has been left empty'
          };
        }
      }
    },

    observers: [
      'statusChanged(status)'
    ],

    statusChanged: function(status) {
      this.status = status;
    },
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure to set `handle-as="json"` in the iron-ajax element so it can correctly parse the received object.

Comment: I added it, but it didn't change the result unfortunatly. Still good to know though, thanks!

Comment: Is it because you're missing an `=` sign @ `as="status"`?

Comment: Do you mind adding that as an answer? :P That solved it xD You have no idea how stupid I feel right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<iron-list items="[[data]]" as "status">
```

to:

```
<iron-list items="[[data]]" as="status">
```